# Spring boot multiple datasource configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource, jdbctemplate

I am trying to configure multiple data sources in spring boot app. But I am getting following error when application is about to boot.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mySQLReplicationStatusService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=msMysqlJdbcTemplate)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:47)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=msMysqlJdbcTemplate)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:47)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

Here is my configuration class looks like:

```
package com.example;
    @Configuration
    public class MultipleDBConfig {


        @Bean(name = "masterMysqlDb")
        @Primary
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.ds_master_mysql")
        public DataSource masterMysqlDataSource() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }

        @Bean(name = "msMysqlJdbcTemplate")
        public JdbcTemplate masterJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("masterMysqlDb") DataSource masterMysqlDb) {
            return new JdbcTemplate(masterMysqlDb);
        }

        @Bean(name = "slaveMysqlDb")
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.ds_slave_mysql")
        public DataSource slaveMysqlDataSource() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }

        @Bean(name = "slaveMysqlJdbcTemplate")
        public JdbcTemplate slaveJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("slaveMysqlDb") DataSource dsSlaveMySQL) {
            return new JdbcTemplate(dsSlaveMySQL);
        }
    }
```

Here is my service class:

```
    package com.example.replication.service;
       @Service
public class MySQLReplicationStatusService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("msMysqlJdbcTemplate")
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("slaveMysqlJdbcTemplate")
    private JdbcTemplate slaveJdbcTemplate;

    public void checkReplicationStatus(String dbName, String tableName){
        System.out.println("In checkReplicationStatus");
        Connection conn_master = null;
        Statement stmt_master = null;
        StringBuilder sbSql_master = null;
        ResultSet rs_master = null;

        Connection conn_slave = null;
        Statement stmt_slave = null;
        StringBuilder sbSql_slave = null;
        ResultSet rs_slave = null;

        try{
            conn_master = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
            stmt_master = conn_master.createStatement();
            sbSql_master = new StringBuilder();
            sbSql_master.append("SELECT COLUMN_NAME");
            sbSql_master.append("FROM information_schema.COLUMNS");
            sbSql_master.append("WHERE (TABLE_SCHEMA = " + dbName + ")");
            sbSql_master.append("AND (TABLE_NAME = " + tableName + ")");
            sbSql_master.append("AND (COLUMN_KEY = 'PRI') ");

            rs_master = stmt_master.executeQuery(sbSql_master.toString());

            /*conn_slave = slaveJdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
            stmt_slave = conn_slave.createStatement();
            sbSql_slave = new StringBuilder();
            sbSql_slave.append("SELECT * FROM ").append(dbName).append(".").append(tableName);
            rs_slave = stmt_slave.executeQuery(sbSql_slave.toString());*/

            if(rs_master != null){
                while(!rs_master.isLast()){
                    rs_master.next();
                    Object obj = rs_master.getObject(1);
                    Object obj2 = rs_master.getObject(2);
                    String key = null;
                    String val = null;
                    if(obj != null){
                        key = obj.toString();
                        System.out.println("Key = " + key);
                    }
                    if(obj2 != null){
                        val = obj2.toString();
                        System.out.println("Value = " + val);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is component class:

```
@Component
public class MySQLReplicationStatusCheck {
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MySQLReplicationStatusCheck.class);

    @Autowired
    private MySQLReplicationStatusService mysqlReplicationStatusService = null;

    @Value("${master.db_name}")
    private  String databaseName;

    @Value("${master.table_name}")
    private  String tableName;

    public void replicationEvent(){
        logger.info("Inside replicationEvent method");
        System.out.println("Inside replicationEvent method");
        mysqlReplicationStatusService.checkReplicationStatus(databaseName, tableName);
    }
}
```

Here is my application.properties:

```
logging.config=./conf/log4j.xml

spring.ds_master_mysql.url = jdbc:mysql://<host>:3306
spring.ds_master_mysql.username = username
spring.ds_master_mysql.password = password
spring.ds_master_mysql.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

 master.db_name=fdmsus_demo
 master.table_name=vitalstats
```

Here is Spring boot class:

```
package com.example;
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class FdmsMysqlReplicationApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(FdmsMysqlReplicationApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

However I am not able to figure out where is I am missing something. Can anyone please help me get this done.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check if the configuration is used?

Comment: @Jens How can I do so?

Comment: Add a breakpoint  and run the code in a Debugger or add some logging statements

Comment: Is configuration I provided is correct?

Comment: Looks ok for me

Comment: I am getting this error then No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=msMysqlJdbcTemplate)}

Comment: Yes i see. But you get it also if the configuration is never readed, because of wrong anotation scan path

Comment: In that case let me add my application.properties file code and boot file code

Comment: Why you not simply use a Debugger?

Comment: I just debug the code and found that it is giving the same error and not even logging or reading any configuration.

Comment: where you have imported configuration class MultipleDBConfig  ? also have you added

Comment: Its in the separate package from main class annotated with @Configuration

Comment: Is the package with the configuration class nested below the package that contains the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class?

Comment: Yes. its like, com.example contains spring boot class and below that com.example.config contains configuration class

Comment: @mahendrakawde Can you please add the package declaration to your classes?

Comment: I just edited question with package declaration added in it.

Comment: @mahendrakawde in a comment you wrot *com.example.config contains configuration class*  in the question the package is *com.example*? Also have you tried to clean and rebuild your Project?

Comment: Now I just move config class into com.example package where @springBootApplication class is reside. So errors now resolved. But my service class is not getting called explicitly. I dont have any controller in my app. How I can call my service class method.

Comment: how are you trying to call it? You just need to autowire your service and call from there

Comment: There is nothing in my @ SpringBootApplication class except main() method. And then there is @ Component class in which I am trying to read property files value and pass it onto the method which in turn calling @Service class which is using JdbcTemplate to connect to the database and excute SELECT query there.

Comment: @Jens I have updated question with added code please see

Comment: @mahendrakawde Sorry do not get your actual question

Answer (score 1):

I think issue is with declaring **driver class name** in application.properties

```
logging.config=./conf/log4j.xml

spring.ds_master_mysql.url = jdbc:mysql://<host>:3306
spring.ds_master_mysql.username = username
spring.ds_master_mysql.password = password
spring.ds_master_mysql.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

 master.db_name=fdmsus_demo
 master.table_name=vitalstats
```

**Use below application.properties**:

```
 logging.config=./conf/log4j.xml

    spring.ds_master_mysql.url = jdbc:mysql://<host>:3306
    spring.ds_master_mysql.username = username
    spring.ds_master_mysql.password = password
    spring.ds_master_mysql.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

     master.db_name=fdmsus_demo
     master.table_name=vitalstats
```

Answer (score 0):

SpringBoot configuration multiple datasource:

application.properties

```
#spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.database=default
logging.level.org.springframework = info
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

# Connection properties of Data Source A
spring.datasource.a.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo1?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.a.jdbcUrl=${spring.datasource.a.url}
spring.datasource.a.username = root
spring.datasource.a.password =
spring.datasource.a.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.a.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect


# Connection properties of Data Source B
spring.datasource.b.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo2?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.b.jdbcUrl=${spring.datasource.b.url}
spring.datasource.b.username = root
spring.datasource.b.password =
spring.datasource.b.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.b.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

ConfigA.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"api.a.repo"})
public class ConfigA {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSourceA")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.a")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactoryA")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                                       @Qualifier("dataSourceA") DataSource dataSource) {

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.show-sql", env.getProperty("spring.datasource.a.jpa.show-sql"));
        properties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", env.getProperty("spring.datasource.a.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("spring.datasource.a.hibernate.dialect"));

        return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .properties(properties)
            .packages("api.a.model")
            .persistenceUnit("datasourceA")
            .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManagerA")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryA") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

ConfigB.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"api.b.repo"})
public class ConfigB {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name = "dataSourceB")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.b")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactoryB")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                                       @Qualifier("dataSourceB") DataSource dataSource) {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.show-sql", env.getProperty("spring.datasource.b.jpa.show-sql"));
        properties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", env.getProperty("spring.datasource.b.hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("spring.datasource.b.hibernate.dialect"));

        return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .packages("api.b.model")
            .persistenceUnit("datasourceB")
            .build();
    }


    @Bean(name = "transactionManagerB")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryB") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

visit : https://github.com/johanmoncada/OpenWork

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue a few days back and solved it. I'm using **spring boot version 3.0.1** and **java version 19**. Here is the source code

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
**for oracle db**
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
**for postgresql db**
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

**application.properties**

```
#first DB MYSQL
first.db.datasource.jdbc-url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db
first.db.datasource.username: 
first.db.datasource.password: 
first.db.datasource.driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#second DB mysql ...
second.db.datasource.jdbc-url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/test_db_2
second.db.datasource.username: 
second.db.datasource.password: 
second.db.datasource.driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Config Class for the first datasource

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "firstDBEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "firstDBTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.*.*.repository"})
public class FirstDbConfig {
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "firstDBDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "first.db.datasource")
    public DataSource firstDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "firstDBEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                                       @Qualifier("firstDBDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.*.*.entity")
                .persistenceUnit("db1").build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "firstDBTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager firstDBTransactionManager(@Qualifier("firstDBEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory firstDBEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(firstDBEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Config Class for the second datasource

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondDBEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "secondDBTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.*.*.seconddb.repository"})
public class SecondDbConfig {

    @Bean(name = "secondDBDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "second.db.datasource")
    public DataSource secondDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondDBEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean secondDBEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("secondDBDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.*.*.seconddb.entity")
                .persistenceUnit("db2")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondDBTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager secondDBTransactionManager(@Qualifier("secondDBEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory secondDBEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(secondDBEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```